# wordpress: Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is require

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I've got this problem after restoring the original php.ini on my shared hosting to disable some dangerous functions like exec. If I rename the php.ini file to anything else my wordpress site works fine. I've installed MySQLi database layer plugin and added the db.php but my index page went blank. How to solve this?

Comment: look for appache error logs.

Comment: Try error_reporting and display_errors.

Comment: [06-Sep-2015 09:44:03 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pspell.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pspell.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[06-Sep-2015 09:44:03 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: timezonedb: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0